# how to set up ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, windows, wubi

I have experimented with Wubi for a few years now and I've finally gotten the hang of it.  I am comfortable enough with Linux rarely if ever refer to my Windows programs.

My laptop has 500 GB and only 32 GB are allocated towards Wubi.  What are my options for setting up my laptop with Ubuntu with even more space

I'd like to have a dual partition with 300GB ubuntu and the rest Windows.

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate if you want to continue with dual boot Ubuntu and Windows, or if you want to delete Windows and install Ubuntu all by itself? In either case, why not go with the default setup? **Make backups of your data** both for Windows, and Ubuntu.

Comment: It may be easier to set up using LiveCD rather than from Wubi, you can then overwrite the Windows installation to use all the Hard Disk space.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean having **2 partitions**, one for each OS, I recommend the use of a **live USB or CD** and reducing the size of the original ext4 partition, now, you'll end up having some *unallocated space*, what you'll do is that you'll set it up a an NTFS and install windows there.

It would be my personal recommendation to create not 1, but 2 NTFS partitions, the reason is that you can back up your data in a NTFS partition (movies, files, etc), without depending on a OS for managing that, you could have dual boot with Ubuntu, windows, and all your data in another partition, and in case something happens and you need a clean install, you won't loose all of your data.

Hope this answer suits you friend, let us know how it was.

Note: When i mean use a live USB or CD, i mean if you have the USB or Ubuntu CD, you just put it in your computer and boot from it, and select the option live (like for testing it), that will give you access to Gparted and then you can do what you need to do, sorry if I wasn't specific here.